# ListTitle Force a Width Infinity?

Tags: flutter

Sorry for my bad English. By Default Does ListTitle Force a Width Infinity? Because I'm trying to put a listTitle as a Row's daughter and I'm getting an error of this nature.

```
Card makeCard(ScheduleModel list) => Card(
  elevation: 4.0,
  margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
  child: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 90.0,
    child: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(                                    
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 5.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: new Color(0xff2b72d0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0))
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
         title: new Text('test'),
         subtitle: new Text('test'),      
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Basically I have a card, where I defined a container as its child, which has defined height and width as infinity, the child of this container is a row with a container of width 5 and infinite height to inherit maximum size from its parent.
The problem occurs whenever I try for a ListTitle as a child of the row, the following error pops up.

```
I/flutter (22402): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22402): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (22402): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (22402): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following
I/flutter (22402): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter (22402):   _RenderListTile._layoutBox (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:1300:9)
I/flutter (22402): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter (22402):   BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=90.0)
I/flutter (22402): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (22402): #0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:504:9)
I/flutter (22402): #1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:545:21)
I/flutter (22402): #2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:551:6)
I/flutter (22402): #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1559:24)
I/flutter (22402): #4      _RenderListTile._layoutBox (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:1300:9)
I/flutter (22402): #5      _RenderListTile.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:1348:28)
I/flutter (22402): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #7      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter (22402): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #15     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:737:15)
I/flutter (22402): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #17     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13)
I/flutter (22402): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #26     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
I/flutter (22402): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #28     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter (22402): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #32     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:737:15)
I/flutter (22402): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #34     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #36     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #38     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:165:27)
I/flutter (22402): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #40     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (22402): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #42     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:407:13)
I/flutter (22402): #43     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1651:12)
I/flutter (22402): #44     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1614:20)
I/flutter (22402): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #46     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #50     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #52     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #56     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #60     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #62     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #64     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (22402): #65     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:431:7)
I/flutter (22402): #66     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (22402): #67     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (22402): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #69     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #71     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (22402): #72     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
I/flutter (22402): #73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter (22402): #74     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (22402): #75     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:431:7)
I/flutter (22402): #76     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (22402): #77     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (22402): #78     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1519:7)
I/flutter (22402): #79     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter (22402): #80     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:347:19)
I/flutter (22402): #81     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (22402): #82     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
I/flutter (22402): #83     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1012:15)
I/flutter (22402): #84     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:952:9)
I/flutter (22402): #85     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:5)
I/flutter (22402): #89     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:10)
I/flutter (22402): #90     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:178:3)
I/flutter (22402): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (22402): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (22402):   _RenderListTile#dc5c0 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):   creator: _ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter (22402):   RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← InkWell ← ListTile ← Row ← ⋯
I/flutter (22402):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (22402):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=90.0)
I/flutter (22402):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (22402): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (22402):   RenderParagraph#0abc6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):   RenderParagraph#88dac NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):   RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#3e83e relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):     RenderPointerListener#e30fb relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):       RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e1992 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):         RenderConstrainedBox#294b5 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402):           RenderPadding#c93ac relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#dc5c0 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#ddab7 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#35755 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#cdbfc relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0e0be relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#a4ebf NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#48544 relayoutBoundary=up25 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bddac relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#3fbe7 relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#bf2d4 relayoutBoundary=up22 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#9a84e relayoutBoundary=up21 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#50962 relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#f9d72 relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#98b22 relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#77b0e relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 470 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#cc77f relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#3994f relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a00ff relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#93c62 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#ea8fc relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#bb618 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#0e8ea relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f470b relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#0a460 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#17488 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#17488 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (22402): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
```

Comment: Problem solved thanks to this post in [medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-part-1-renderflex-children-have-non-zero-flex-e25ffcf7c272).

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` by usually inherits its parent widget's dimension to fill into. What's likely happens in this case is that the layout is unbounded and ListTile gets an infinite width. One way to resolve this issue is by defining a weight on your `Row` by using [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) on its children. Using the `flex` property of Expanded divides the free space according to the flex factors of the flexible children.

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Container(...),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: ListTile(
        title: new Text('test'),
        subtitle: new Text('test'),      
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```